# Node server.js not responding and thows error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

I am starts working on expressJs nodeJs but stuck at a beginning point to run the node server.js command. I think any module is missing to install but i`m not recognize which one is missing.Im working on linux(ubuntu) operating system. Please help me to out this problem.

```
iron@iron-System-Product-Name:/media/iron/1d6c195f-2350-423c-a3f0-0500c92e580a/admin-panel/node-admin-master$ node server.js
module.js:442
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/media/iron/1d6c195f-2350-423c-a3f0-0500c92e580a/admin-panel/node-admin-master/config/env/undefined'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/iron/1d6c195f-2350-423c-a3f0-0500c92e580a/admin-panel/node-admin-master/config/routes.js:6:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/iron/1d6c195f-2350-423c-a3f0-0500c92e580a/admin-panel/node-admin-master/server.js:14:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
```

Node Version: v6.2.2
Npm version: 3.9.5

Answer (score 0):

it take undefined of variable which may you declare in **config/env/undefined**.
Please check your env file or if possible share with me .

Thanks

Comment: or you can do this:      rm -rf node_modules
npm install -g

Answer (score 0):

With the error, i suspect you are missing [iron-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iron-node) module. 
To simply install in project, run

```
npm i iron-node
```

to install and save it in the project's package.json, run:

```
npm i iron-node --save
```

to install it in your computer, do:

```
npm i -g iron-node
```

However, since this is a development dependency, you should install it as one and save it in package.json, by:

```
npm i iron-node -D --save
```